# Cheaper alternative to OEM hoods for long exposure filters

Tags: filters, long-exposure, lens-hood, lee

I've got several Lee filters with holder by the manufacturer. I'm looking for a hood, but the one sold by Lee is very expensive.

Did anybody find a cheaper alternative?

[image]

Comment: The Mamiya G3 bellows hood is very similar, but I can't find exact measurements and am not sure if it can be used as a direct replacement. It is not exactly cheap either, but I got mine used in a very good state for about US$ 50.

Comment: @xiota Long exposure is very relevant to this question. When using ND filters with high density on the front of the holder without an equally high density material preventing light leaks around the sides/edges of holders the influence of the light leaks is increased greatly compared to the light entering through the filters.

Comment: The accepted answer states: "when you slow down to shoot a long exposure, a dedicated hood really isn't necessary anymore."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the lens hood is to cast a shadow on the lens so that the only light being picked up is the light you're pointing the lens at - any glare causing strays get blocked.

Hoods are super useful when you are chasing the action. But, when you slow down to shoot a long exposure, a dedicated hood really isn't necessary anymore.

All you need to do is cast a shadow onto your lens and block those stray glare-causing rays.

And for this, you can use almost anything. If the sun is low in the sky, your body might be a good option. Reflector/Scrim/T-shirt/Rain Cover/Tarp/Umbrella...anything that you can find will just about work. Bonus points for you and your arms if you can find a way to rig it to stay in place. (Do keep in mind that you *don't* want to rig it to the tripod, as any wind will send your rig runnin')